# Data missing imputation with autoencoder on small set of data

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I have to model a ANN to predict the level of consumer complains regarding the in-process parameters on the chain production for my master thesis. Unfortunately, the firm gives me unregulated collected data and there are a lot of missing data. It's about a year of data grouped by open day, so I have 17 column of physical values for 260 days. To infer the missing values, I try to model an denoising autoencoder but it doesn't provide good results. For training the model, I have only 113 days with complete data. The values are real-valued, with different unit and range (some are in the range (100,150) and others are in (90.03,90.35)).

To simulate noise and like the missing dynamic is Not Random At All, I modify a value, with this condition (Random.random()

```
def DAE(train,l1,l2,num_layer):
    input_size = train.shape[1]
    #num_layer = 2
    theta = 1 #int(input_size/num_layer)
    code_size = input_size-theta*(num_layer+1)
    epochss=1000  
    lrr=0.01

    autoencoder = Sequential()
    autoencoder.add(Dense(input_size, input_shape=(input_size,), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
            activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)))

    for index in range(num_layer):
        layer_size=input_size-(index+1)*theta
        autoencoder.add(Dense(layer_size,input_shape=(input_size,),activation='linear'))
        print(layer_size)

    autoencoder.add(Dense(code_size,activation='linear'))
    print(code_size) 

    for index in range(num_layer):
        layer_size=input_size-(num_layer-index)*theta
        autoencoder.add(Dense(layer_size,input_shape=(input_size,),activation='linear'))
        print(layer_size)

    autoencoder.add(Dense(input_size,activation='linear'))
    autoencoder.compile(Adam(lr=lrr), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return autoencoder

autoencoder = DAE(AE_train,l1,l2,3)
history = autoencoder.fit(AE_train,AE_target,epochs=1000,validation_split=0.2)
```

On train and test loss plot, it converge really fastly but after a certain number of epochs it appears a big peak with log decay just after. I don't understand why it rise.

When I try to predict the missing values, I change the nan by the mean of the column. The prediction is always out of the min max range of the specific physical values.

So here are my question, how can I deal with missing data in a small set of values ? Here I have different type of values(unit), should I normalize the values ? But if a do that, how to reconstruct them, as I want to infer real value. Is there a better solution for missing data imputation than autoencoder in ML family techniques?

Thanks for reading my problem and even more for bring me an answer.

[Loss plot for test and train sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx28O.png)

Comment: If you don't mind, you'd better post your whole code.@Jojo